# Crear una matriz con una lista de listas

Tags: python, lista, numpy, matriz

Quiero saber si es posible imprimir una matriz con una lista de strings ya obtenida, por ejemplo:

```
alfabeto = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'k']

alfabeto_numerico = [(str([numeros])) for numeros in range(len(alfabeto))]

print(alfabeto_numerico)

>>> ['[0]', '[1]', '[2]', '[3]', '[4]', '[5]', '[6]', '[7]', '[8]', '[9]', '[10]', '[11]']
```

Y mi idea seria que quede algo así:

```
['[0]', '[1]', '[2]', '[3]',
 '[4]', '[5]', '[6]', '[7]',
 '[8]', '[9]', '[10]', '[11]']
```

Y en lo posible dejarlo así:

```
 [0] [1] [2] [3]
 [4] [5] [6] [7]
 [8] [9] [10] [11]
```

Intente realizarlo iterando la lista 2 veces con el numero de filas/columnas pero se me sale de rango ya que mi lista tiene 1 solo string y tampoco se como encararlo.

Comment: Solución extremadamente fácil: no conviertas a string

Answer (score 1):

No se que flexibilidad necesitas a la hora de segun los caracteres formar la matriz pero te dejo un codigo que resuelve lo que intentas hacer en ese ejemplo especifico por si te sirve!

```
alfabeto = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']
matriz = []
corte = 4
sub_matriz = []
for numeros in range(len(alfabeto)):
    if not numeros%corte and numeros:
        matriz.append(sub_matriz)
        sub_matriz = []
    sub_matriz.append(numeros)
matriz.append(sub_matriz)

print(matriz) #[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
```